# Project doesn't display "Import Project" referenced files (System.Data.SQLite solution)

Tags: visual-studio, system.data.sqlite, projects-and-solutions

I have some trouble with loading a [System.Data.SQLite source solution](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/timeline?n=20&y=ci). The `System.Data.SQLite.2010` project seems to be empty, it is, indeed, does not contain references to files. However project file contains strings like these:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\System.Data.SQLite.References.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\System.Data.SQLite.Properties.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\System.Data.SQLite.Files.targets" />
```

which, actually, contain references to files. But it's looks like this `Import Project` instructions are ignored by my VS. Is there is something I miss to do? Or maybe I need some plugin to install? Solution is builded successfully from VS, I just want to see files so I can navigate more easily on source.

Comment: Got latest and both System.Data.SQLite.2010 and System.Data.SQLite.Module.2010 projects have had all their files excluded. I have had a go at re-including the files (all present), but the projects are in a mess and I can't get them to build yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not missing any plugins, nor is VS ignoring the `Import` directives. The import directives are used when build the project.

If you build the project, it builds fine and has all the classes that can be found in System.Data.SQLite*.cs.

I guess one of the reasons why this was done to protect 'core' framework files from accidental modification.

If you would like to see those files in your solution folder -

1. Open up *System.Data.SQLite.Files.targets* and *System.Data.SQLite.2010.csproj* in notepad or your favorite editor
2. Copy both `ItemGroup` nodes and paste them in *System.Data.SQLite.2010.csproj*
3. Comment out `<Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\System.Data.SQLite.Files.targets" />` and save the csproj file.
4. Open up the solution file again or if already opened, reload the project to see the files.

Here's what my csproj looks after above modification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
 *
 * System.Data.SQLite.2010.csproj -
 *
 * Written by Joe Mistachkin.
 * Released to the public domain, use at your own risk!
 *
-->
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>10.0.30319</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{AC139952-261A-4463-B6FA-AEBC25283A66}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>System.Data.SQLite</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>System.Data.SQLite</AssemblyName>
    <OldToolsVersion>3.5</OldToolsVersion>
    <SQLiteNetDir>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..</SQLiteNetDir>
    <ConfigurationYear>2010</ConfigurationYear>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(SQLiteNetDir)\SQLite.NET.Settings.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(BinaryOutputPath)' != ''">
    <OutputPath>$(BinaryOutputPath)</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>$(BinaryOutputPath)System.Data.SQLite.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\System.Data.SQLite.References.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\System.Data.SQLite.Properties.targets" />
  <!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\System.Data.SQLite.Files.targets" />-->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLite3.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLite3_UTF16.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteBase.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteCommand.cs">
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="SQLiteCommandBuilder.cs">
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="SQLiteConnection.cs">
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="SQLiteConnectionPool.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteConvert.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteDataAdapter.cs">
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="SQLiteDataReader.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteException.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteFactory.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteFunction.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteFunctionAttribute.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteKeyReader.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteMetaDataCollectionNames.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteParameter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteParameterCollection.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteStatement.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SQLiteTransaction.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SR.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>SR.resx</DependentUpon>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UnsafeNativeMethods.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="SR.resx">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>SR.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(IsCompactFramework)' == 'false'">
    <Compile Include="SQLiteEnlistment.cs" />
    <Compile Include="LINQ\SQLiteConnection_Linq.cs">
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="LINQ\SQLiteFactory_Linq.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="SQLiteCommand.bmp" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="SQLiteConnection.bmp" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="SQLiteDataAdapter.bmp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it.
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: Not solves my problem in a way I want (proposed solution is of course obvious), but at least I know I'm not missing some Visual Studio features.